# STL algorithm to repeat an erase operation on a second container?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers, erase

Life gave me the following objects:

- `std::vector<T1> v1;`
- `std::vector<T2> v2;`
- `typename std::vector<T1>::iterator it_first;`
- `typename std::vector<T1>::iterator it_last;`

and the following constraints:

- `v1.size() == v2.size() > 0`
- `v1.begin() <= it_first <= it_last <= v1.end()`

Removing from `v1` the range pointed by the two iterators is a trivial single line, but how do I **remove the same range also from `v2`**?

I can easily solve this for instance by building `v2` iterators using a mix of `std::distance/advance`, but I was wondering if the **STL** provides some machinery for this. Something like the erase-remove idiom coupled with a transform operation, maybe? It seems beyond my STL-fu...

Comment: That range is defined by its iterators, which point into `v1`. It is not a range in `v2`, so be very careful about what you mean by "the same range".

Comment: I have found an implementation of `eraser_iterator` in a library called STLSoft: https://github.com/synesissoftware/STLSoft-1.10/blob/beta-18/include/stlsoft/iterator/eraser_iterator.hpp I have no experience concerning the usability for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have an iterator, then you can get the index via [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to `begin()`.

When you have an index, then you can get the iterator via `begin() + index`.

Thats bascially all you need to get the same range of incdices in the second vector.

Btw iterators are to abstract away the index. When you need the index, then work with the index. For `erase` that would be

```
size_t start = 1;
size_t end = 42;
std::erase( v1.begin() + start, v1.begin() + end );
std::erase( v2.begin() + start, v2.begin() + end );
```

> I can easily solve this for instance by building v2 iterators using a mix of std::distance/advance, but I was wondering if the STL provides some machinery for this. Something like the erase-remove idiom coupled with a transform operation, maybe? It seems beyond my STL-fu...

I saw the edit only after writing the answer. The thing is `std::distance` / `std::advance` **is** the machinery to switch between iterators and indices.

Consider that iterators in general are for things that can be iterated. You do not even necesarily need a container to iterate. For example you could write an iterator type that lets you iterate integers. This iterator type could be used like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> x(100);
auto begin = int_iterator(0);
auto end   = int_iterator(100);
for ( ; begin != end; ++begin) std::cout << x[ *begin ];
```

This is no C-ism. The example is perhaps not the best, but the `int_iterator` itself is on par with the general concept of iterators.
Usually iterators have no knowledge about the underlying container (if there is one). There are few exceptions (eg `insert_iterator`). And in case of `erase` of course you need to pass iterators that refer to element in the corresponding container.

Comment: I think that the point here is to avoid stepping back to the indexes. I got the iterators from some other algorithms. Do I really need to use `std::distance` to go back to indexes and `std::advance` to go back to iterators? It's fine for sure, but ...really?

Comment: @DarioP why do you think there would be something wrong with this? What else are you looking for?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this approach, in fact I even mentioned it in the question! The thing is that if I am working with iterators I shouldn't need to step back to indexes or pointers or whatever IMHO. I wasn't asking a practical question, more about style and elegance.

Comment: @DarioP if you need an index then you need an index. Iterators are only valid for a single container. Actually I would call it bad style when you use iterators when you actually want indices

Comment: @DarioP btw I saw your edit only after writing the answer, you first made no mention of `advance` or `distance`

Comment: I originally made a general reference to C-style, then rethought it making it more appropriate while you were answering. No problem anyway. Concerning index vs iterator my opinion is that if I am using a bunch of STL algorithms which accept and return iterators, stepping back to indexes is like having to step back from C++ to C: it surely works, but shouldn't be needed and it is not elegant.

Comment: @DarioP then i can only repeat.No offense, but you are wrong. Iterators are to give you an abstraction that is more abstract than indices. For example when you call `std::erase(it_first, it_second)` then you are basically saying "I dont care about indices".  Most of the time when using an algorithm you really do not care about the index of the elements. For example in a `map` the "index" is almost meaningless. But if you do care about the index (eg because you need to access same range of indices in two containers) then you need indices...

Comment: I can for sure be wrong, no offence involved otherwise I would't be here. I was probably expecting to find something like a `std::insert_iterator` but to erase instead of inserting. Now I wonder if it could be written, but this is another question!

Comment: @idclev463035818 -- re: "Iterators are only valid for a single container" -- you're right that iterators into a container are only valid for that container. But iterators are more abstract than that. Iterators designate a range. Containers are one way of managing ranges, but they are not the only way.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks. I wasnt in best conditions yesterday. Your comment helped me to explain better

Comment: @DarioP I added another edit. Hope this helps to clarify